# django templates to views does not render to models data

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

this is my django 1.8 project, however it does not shows the models' data in the admin:

[image]

My admin site has some posts but it does not show on the web:

[image]

Directory tree:

[image]

> mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog', app_name='blog')),
]
```

> blog/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    # post views
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.post_detail,
        name='post_detail'),
]
```

> blog/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {'posts': posts})



def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                                   status='published',
                                   publish__year=year,
                                   publish__month=month,
                                   publish__day=day)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post': post})
```

> blog/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')



class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    published = PublishedManager() # The Dahl-specific manager.



    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                       args=[self.publish.year,
                             self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                             self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                             self.slug])
```

> blog/templates/blog/base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static "css/blog.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <h2>My blog here</h2>
        <p>This is my blog.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> blog/templates/blog/post/list.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}My Blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>My Blog up</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h2><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
        {{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <p class="date">Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}</p>
        {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
    {% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

> blog/templates/blog/post/detail.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ post.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <p class="date">Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}</p>
    {{ post.body|linebreaks }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Because none of your posts are in the `published` status.

Comment: oh,,,yes,,,I got it,,thank you so much T_T

Comment: excuse me,,sir,,,when I Click the link in blog ,,that shows "No Post matches the given query"?I got no idea what happen ??thank you http://stackoverflow.com/q/36314031/5678590

Comment: I think it is about mysql's problem,,when I try the same code in sqlite3,it can work (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314031/no-post-matches-the-given-query)